# How do I get the username in a self-hosted ServiceStack running on Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, security, servicestack

I'm building a `Windows service` and instead of exposing a WCF or .Net remoting interface, I'm giving `ServiceStack` a shot. (So far, I'm digging it!)

I need to get the `Username` of the user calling the service.  The user will have already been authenticated against Active Directory so I don't want them to see any additional screens.

The service will be called by a Winforms application so I `COULD` pass in the username, but that could be `spoofed`.

any ideas?

Comment: This just isn't possible.  Users don't "call" a service.  Services run in their own isolated session with your own user account, typically "System".  If this is important then you should *not* use a service, just a regular program that you start with a shortcut in the user's Startup folder.

Comment: The users will be using a program that calls methods exposed by my service, something akin to an RPC call.  With .net remoting, I could pick up the credentials off the thread.

Comment: Not sure you can do it out of the box with ServiceStack. Take a look at this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/servicestack/OaLGCvoXp3A

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so basically this ain't supported by ServiceStack. 
But you can get the username by doing like this.

```
namespace ServiceStackNTML
{
   using ServiceStack.Common;
   using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
   using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
   using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;
   using System;
   using System.Net;

   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var host = new NTMLAppHost();
           host.Init();
           host.Start("http://localhost:8080/");

           Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }

   class NTMLAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
   {
       public NTMLAppHost() : base("Test", typeof(NTMLAppHost).Assembly) { }

       public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
       {

       }

       public override void Start(string urlBase)
       {
           base.Start(urlBase);
           this.Listener.AuthenticationSchemes = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
       }

       protected override void ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
       {
           HostContext.Instance.Items["User"] = context.User;
           base.ProcessRequest(context);
       }
   }

   class TestService : Service
   {
       public string Any(UsernameRequest request)
       {
           return ((System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal)HostContext.Instance.Items["User"]).Identity.Name;
       }
   }

   [Route("/Username")]
   class UsernameRequest : IReturn<string>
   {

   }
}
```